# Cant Find the position of a letter in the string

Tags: javascript

I got a string Like this

```
var test = "１２３４５６７８９０ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ"
```

Actually I can't find the position of "t" in this string. don't know why,
I used indexOf, tried to convert this into string object, but all got in vain

note : Please use the exact string given in the question, 
Thanks,

Comment: `test.indexOf('t')`

Comment: Without spaces, `test.split(' ').indexOf('t')`

Comment: @Rayon it gives -1 (test.split(' ').indexOf('t'))

Comment: @Rayon If we are using the exact string we wont get the position of "t"

Comment: In what sense is it not working for you? Are you getting an error? What is the error? Are you getting an unexpected result? What is the result? What were you expecting?

Comment: `test.indexOf('ｔ')` will work!

Comment: I guess this font maps the letters we see to some other characters.

Comment: @Redu I have another question, is there any way that we can change this fonts to normal lowercase string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are non-standard characters, so to search for the "t" in in, you have to actually copy and paste the `ｔ` from your string.

```
>> test.indexOf("ｔ")
>> 29
```

---

For demonstration:

```
"t".charCodeAt()
116 // ASCII code for lowercase t

"ｔ".charCodeAt()
65364 // Something non-standard
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't find because it's not 't' you are trying to find. Take a look at `"ｔ".charCodeAt(0)` which returns 65364 and `"t".charCodeAt(0)` which yields 116. Those are different characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.prototype.indexOf()` which will return the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value.

Please note that `t` in your string is a "non-standard character" and won't be found by `indexOf()` if you use a "standard character ".

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

```js
var test = "１２３４５６７８９０ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ";
console.log(test.indexOf("ｔ"));
```